# Удалить все символы, кроме: . и @, а также обычных букв

Tags: php

Нужно удалить из переменной все символы, которые там есть, но оставить:

- **обычные буквы**(a, b, c, d...)
- **@** (собаку)
- **.** (точку)

Как такое сделать?

Или осуществить проверку. Т.е. если там присутствует что-то другое, то не выполнять.
Т.е.

```
 if (preg_match('выражение', $peremennaya)) {
выполняем
}
else {
нет
}
```

Comment: [собственно твой же вопрос][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/75318/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t_double_arrow-expecting

Comment: есть еще знак евро и много-много других знаков (например, китайские буквы), которые не набираются могут присутствовать, и которые пропустит тот вариант.
К тому же кто его знает, может еще какие-то символы добавят.

Comment: Вот еще пример: ♪◙. Таких знаков тысячи, если не больше...

Comment: так вот именно что проще проверить на нужное значение нежели удалять и проверять на ненужные символы геморройно и неправильно.

если проверять на все, то это не айс.

Comment: Да я понял и исправил. К тому же, если обрезать, то там в кашу потом оставшийся текст образуется и ничего с ним не сделаешь. Надо проверять на соответствие регулярке, как написал timka_s. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замена

```
preg_replace( '/[^a-zA-Z@\.]/', '', $str );
```

или проверка:

```
if ( preg_match( '/[^a-zA-Z@\.]/', $str ) ) die('symbol');
```

Можно использовать такое Re:

```
/[^a-z@\.]/i
```

А при UTF:

```
/[^a-z@\.]/iu
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать `str_replace("[a-z][0-9]","",$peremenaya)`

Comment: a-z у вас тоже исчезнут, а их надо оставить